# How to do greater (>) and lesser (<) scripts?

Tags: php

I am using this script below.  I need the "next" to show only when there are more than 10 entries.

code:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $startrow, 10")or
         die(mysql_error());
/*
this next options shows regarldess if there are more than 10 queries or less.  
How can i make it so that it shows only when there are more than 10 queries.
*/ 
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+10).'">Next</a>';
$prev = $startrow - 10;
//only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
if ($prev >= 0)
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform a separate query to count the number of rows in the table: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`, and check if the returned number is greater than <strike>10</strike> `$startrow + 10`.

Comment: I am trying:   $next = $startrow + 10;

if ($next >= 0)

echo 'next';

else if ($next <= 0)

echo '';        I am not sure why it won't work.

Comment: @KPO: `$startrow + 10` tells you how many rows there must be in order for you to show the link - but calculating that number and putting it into `$next` doesn't get you anywhere if you don't check how many rows there _actually_ are in the database. You need to run the query I showed, and compare the result to `$next`.

Answer (score 1):

A word of advice. Don't rewrite something that's been done a thousand times. What you are trying to accomplish is called Pagination (Page by page displaying of data). It's commonly part of most PHP frameworks; such as CodeIgniter or CakePHP. There are also plugin classes out there which will help you greatly.

Google Search:
http://www.google.com/search?q=php+pagination

As other have already mentioned you'll typically need two queries. One query for the subset of results (number per page & an offset point) and one query for the total number of results. Try to find an existing class to help you with your paginating.

Good luck, Jeff Walters